# Oracle SQL - Partition dataset by column value and quantity, then retrieve first and last rows from each partition

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a data set shown below:

[image: Sample Dataset]

And I am trying to partition the data by Group#, Sub-Group#, Product, and Ship To address. Each partition should not have more than 3 rows of records. So even if all the above conditions were met, the 4th record will be in a new partition.

Currently my SQL statement looks like this:

```
Select Group#,
       Sub_Group#,
       Product,
       Ship_To,
       MIN(Sub_Group_Index) KEEP(DENSE_RANK ORDER BY SUB_GROUP_INDEX) OVER (PARTITION BY SHIP_TO) AS MIN_INDEX,
       MAX(Sub_Group_Index) KEEP(DENSE_RANK ORDER BY SUB_GROUP_INDEX) OVER (PARTITION BY SHIP_TO) AS MAX_INDEX
FROM [sample_table]
```

But I cannot figure out how to partition each 3 rows of the same conditions so the data can be displayed like below image:

[image: Data Set after grouping and partitioning]

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` and `group by`:

```
Select Group#, Sub_Group#, Product, Ship_To,
       MIN(Sub_Group_Index) as MIN_INDEX, MAX(Sub_Group_Index) AS MAX_INDEX
from (select st.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Group#, Sub_Group#, Product, Ship_To order by uniqueid) as seqnum
      from [sample_table] st
     ) st
group by Group#, Sub_Group#, Product, Ship_To, trunc((seqnum - 1) / 3);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I tried your suggestion and it worked! I managed to extract the first and last index number for every three records meeting the selection criteria. However, I will need to extract the unique id for the first and last records as well, and when I put uniqueid in the select statement I get a NOT a GROUP BY EXPRESSION error, which I understand. How can I work around it to display min and max index number AND the associated record unique ID?

Comment: @user1759827 . . . I don't fully understand what you are asking for in the comment.  New questions should be asked as questions rather than comments.